# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running slow on my hardware

Tags: performance

Long time Windows user here. Recently I've made the switch to Linux (Ubuntu) and I've spent the past couple of weeks learning the ins and outs of the OS and customizing it to my liking. It was awesome for a few days, everything was snappy and applications were loading quicker than on my Windows OS, which I expected.

Now all of a sudden my Ubuntu OS is running slow (I am dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu) It's taking at least 4-5 seconds to load some applications, particularly Firefox and CLion two applications I use religiously on a daily basis. Another problem is; running commands on the Terminal now takes 2-3 seconds to load the application or function of the command.

I thought maybe it might be some the themes I've installed so I did some troubleshooting and I removed all themes and set my Ubuntu back to default to see if that makes any difference, and nope still running slow.

Specs:

- CPU: i7 7700k 4.2ghz
- GPU: EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti FTW3 Ultra Gaming
- Memory: 32GB
- Storage: SAMSUNG 970 EVO PLUS M.2 2280 1TB SSD
- Monitor: ASUS ROG SWIFT PG279Q 27" 2560x1440 IPS 165Hz

Comment: What kind of customizations did you do?  New users of Linux coming from Windows often make the big mistake of treating Linux like Windows.  They are very different.  It's hard to tell if this is a problem with Ubuntu or perhaps a problem that you inadvertently spawned when you installed software or made tweaks.  Can you give us some more info on that?  Did you install any software outside of the package manager?  Please provide exact details like the commands that you ran, etc.

Comment: Yes I have added numerous software applications since installing Ubuntu, I have installed CLion, I have installed the old software manager the original I don't use Snap store anymore, I have download Taskbook from the command line using sudo apt install taskbook, I have install sublime text through the software application that comes with Ubuntu, I have switched to proprietary driver NVIDIA in the NVIDIA settings application. I have installed neofetch through the command line, I have installed gnome tweaks, extensions, and I have installed numerous themes and icon packs, manually.

Comment: Somewhere in there probably lies your problem, but it's still hard to tell because you haven't given any specifics on *how* you performed these tasks.  How (and why) did you "install the old software manager"?  Did you not choose to download updates and accept 3rd party software when you installed Ubuntu?  For software, you should use `apt` or the GUI package manager.  If software is not available in Ubuntu repositories, you should try to find a *safe* way to install these applications.  Snap is safer than PPA is safer than `.deb` file, is safer than other methods.

Comment: I recommend as a new user to avoid temptation to go with off-spec customizations right off the bat.  If you want to tweak/customize your desktop, I suggest trying another of the [official flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours), like Kubuntu with KDE.  You can "try" each flavor without installing by booting live from the USB. GNOME is practically unconfigurable without digging under the hood and as a new user, unfamiliar with what's going on under the hood, this is probably not a good path.

Comment: Thank you for your response, makes sense. Since this is pretty much a brand new OS I am going to try and reinstall Ubuntu fresh and I will be a little more cautious with what I download and install as far as software and themes are concerned. I will also be more careful and take note of each software I install, and I will take your advice and try to install using software manager or snap store, to keep my application more organized, since all the software I've needed so far is available through the software manager. I will update

Comment: The reason why I installed software and other things like themes and icons packs manually was more for me to learn the different ways to install packages, because I am learning, also I read on the web that someone had this exact issue and solved it by installing Ubuntu 19.04 then upgrading to 20.04 and for them it fixed the slow loading application problems i'm having. I don't see how this makes any sense but I will give it a shot.

Comment: I can't think of any reasons why it would be a benefit to first install an older release.  Especially since both 19.xx operating systems have gone EOL.  19.04 - 20.04 is not a supported upgrade path since it skips over 19.10 (which is now also EOL).  The GUI software center relies on `apt-get`/`dpkg` backend.  `apt` and the software center will resolve dependencies and keep the software update.  It's when you start adding software outside of this system where things can get a little messy, because they don't account for dependencies and updates can break them

Comment: & snap and similar installation methods use a container or container-like system to keep packages updated and with the right dependencies.

Comment: If you look at the hardware specs there should be no reason why Ubuntu is slower than windows. (Usually the other way around). What is the output of `journalctl -p 3 -xb`? (errors since the last boot)

Comment: -- Logs begin at Fri 2020-11-20 13:03:48 EST, end at Fri 2020-11-20 14:15:16 EST. -- 

Nov 20 13:03:48 ms-7a71 kernel: Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed 
Nov 20 13:03:54 ms-7a71 wpa_supplicant[815]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring 
Nov 20 13:04:01 ms-7a71 gdm-password][1394]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file 
Nov 20 13:04:16 ms-7a71 pulseaudio[1408]: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)

Answer (score 1):

Resolved.

Arc-Darkest-COLORS Icon-Superpack was the reason my system was running slow, after
removing the icon set my Ubuntu OS is running smooth again. Shame, it was a really nice icon set lol